# ValidationMessage is throwing conversion error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My MVC5 view is throwing an error when rendering. I'm not sure why, or how to trace it.

The error is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.

The razer is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogoUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogoUrl, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogoUrl, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullTimeEnrollment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullTimeEnrollment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @* This next line errors, not sure why *@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullTimeEnrollment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
    </div>
</div>
```

The model is defined like this:

```
public class Organization : BaseEntity, IAuditableEntity
{
    //...
    [Display(Name = "FullTime Enrollment")]
    public string FullTimeEnrollment { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

My controller is loading the view like this:

```
public ActionResult organizationdetails(Guid? id)
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated("You must be logged in to access this page.", string.Empty))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Submission", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath });
    }
    ViewData["OrgId"] = id;
    ViewBag.Title = id == Guid.Empty ? "Create Organization" : "Edit Organization";
    var org = db.Organization.Find(id);
    ViewBag.OrganizationTypes = Lookups.GetCached(CachedLists.OrganizationTypes) as List<OrganizationType>;

    return View(org);
}
```

The error is on '@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullTimeEnrollment'. When I check the controller, the model looks fine. FullTimeEnrollment is null.

How can I debug this type of problem?

Comment: I would suggest looking into the display template being used for the "@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullTimeEnrollment..."

Comment: Razor does not always indicate where the error is and its probably not the line of code you think. In any case, you do not have any validation attributes on property `FullTimeEnrollment` so not sure what the point of your `ValidationMessageFor()` is.